# Out of memory error when rendering simple ocean modifier (20GB)

Tags: memory-management

[image]

I was experiencing issues with the OCEAN modifier, and then I tried to render it alone, and the same error occured  (only 10.000 faces).

I have seen a tut in which the guy used way higher resolution, and still, it was showing relatively fast and flawlessly in Cycles.

I have 20gb, and the render crashes after ramping-up from 7 to 15gb of full mem usage (still very high for a subdivided plane with a modifier in it).

I have tried to attach the .blend file, but I don't see that option here anymore.
[image]

Thank you.

Comment: You could be running out of VRAM. Are you using very large textures?

Comment: Check out the resolution in the ocean modifier : Like the subdiv modifier, there is one for viewport and one for render (Yours is set to x10 in render)

Comment: It's not video, there is no texture at all, just transparency BSDF.
Regarding the resolution, I am setting a big scene with ocean and mountains. If I use less than 100, the ocean looks like a pound

Comment: B.T.W. I've tested on both 2.93 and 3.00 builds.  Same outcome.

Comment: Well, I have found a solution for achieving a high-resolution ocean, with lower settings. https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/107812/ocean-modifier-color-and-foam Thanks to https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/29370/cgslav